# C# sql server conversion failed error nvarchar value to int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, type-conversion

How to fix this issue in my code:

```
str = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM [tableA] where Company_ID=" + HaksId.ToString() + "";
cmd.CommandText = str;
cmd.Connection = conn;
adpt.SelectCommand = cmd;
adpt.Fill(ds);
```

In the above code there is only required things mentioned obviously conn is connection string I have mentioned all things they are working fine there is some other error in this code

Where `columnname` is string and `Id` is integer

Error is

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[Select]' to data type int.

Return value is value of type `decimal(18,0)`

Hoping for your suggestion

Thanks

**EDITED**

```
columname="Avg"
HaksId=1
```

`Company_ID` is of `nvarchar`

Result of query should be 2.

**SOLUTION**

This help me out,

```
"SELECT " + columnName + " FROM [tableA] where Company_ID='" + HaksId+ "'"
```

Comment: We can't see the values of `columnName` or `HaksId`; so: what is the resulting value of `str` here? Also: Does `ds.Tables[0]` have columns defined? If so: as what?

Comment: Whate is the data type for Company_ID in table

Comment: Company_ID = int isn't it? if it's, then u're comparing it with string.

Comment: I would suggest using a parameter for the ID. It might also help with the confusion of types.

Comment: i have mentioned all things above kindly check it

Comment: @user3664724 It is still safer to use parameters as much as possible for security reasons (sql insertion). I strongly recommend looking at FizzBuzz's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters *should* solve the problem here.
I would change this;

```
str = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM [tableA] where Company_ID=" + HaksId.ToString() + "";
```

To this;

```
str = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM [tableA] where Company_ID = @CompanyID";
```

Then use this;

```
adpt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Haks;
adpt.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: columnID does not exsis in the current context

Comment: See [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) - I would recommend to use a "normal" `Parameters.Add(....).Value = ....` approach.

Comment: @FizzBuzz: read the article I linked to! It explains in great detail why `AddWithValue` is dangerous

Comment: @marc_s Err, didn't realise it was a link, my bad. Nice article and duly noted.